# How to restrict nginx server to a single ip on a multi ip server

Tags: nginx

I have multiple websites running under a server with two IPs. How do I configure nginx to listen at just one ip?

For example:

IP: 192.168.10.10 with nginx (multidomain)

IP: 192.168.10.11 - etc...

The main intention here is to split front office applications from back office tools. I'm not sure how I could limit nginx to use only one IP address like I can do using ssh server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your nginx.config file specify the IP address in the server block :

```
server {
    listen 192.168.10.10:80;
...
}
```

Comment: oh damn, why i didn't checked that .... Thanks for refreshing my memory :)